# How to auto repeat counter in label and call an event when reach maximum count.

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a program that has a counter until 5 and when reach 5 it will auto click a button and  must count back from 0 - 5 again and again every time reach 5.

below is my code in timer click.

```
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TargetDT.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
    If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 0 Then
        lblTime2.Text = ts.ToString("ss")
    Else
        lblTime2.Text = "00"
        Timer2.Stop()
        btnRefresh.PerformClick()
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    messagebox.show 'me dot click'
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Put a static integer variable inside your timer_tick handler, increment it at each tick, and when it reaches a certain value then refresh your form AND reset the counter variable. If you have problems with that, post the code

Comment: @soohoonigan they don't even need to do that, they just need a timer that ticks every 10 seconds and refreshes the form by the sounds of it

Comment: @Jaxi Ya you're probably right...I shouldn't be writing SO comments on a Monday morning before I've finished my coffee

Comment: @soohoonigan If it works it works :P

Comment: If you include the relevant code we may be able to help. PLease read [ask] and most importantly here  [mcve]. Cheers.

Comment: @soohoonigan please help me i add my code already, last night i couldn't copy paste it because i asked question using my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
here is my solution to my question:
```

when the timer tick i auto increment my label 1- 5 and when it reach 5 it will return to 0 and count again 1 - 5. and repeat.  then can do something after reach 0. hope can help

```
      Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + 1
    If Label1.Text = "5" Then
        Label1.Text = 0
        btnRefresh.PerformClick()


    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just set `Timer1.Interval = 5000`, then all you need in `Tick()` is `btnRefresh.PerformClick()`

Comment: thank you @soohoonigan plese help vote my question to increase my reputation. Sir.